# Text below videos in the jQuery Colorbox

Tags: jquery, css, colorbox

I need to put some descriptions below videos. I use Colorbox from here http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

I try to add it as last children to `#cboxLoadedContent`, but it affects as a scrollbar on the div.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could you the title property:

**JQuery**

```
$('a.gallery').colorbox({
    rel:'gal',
    title: 'Video title'
});
```

Alternatively you could use the `inline: true` property:

**JQuery**

```
$('.inline').colorbox({
    rel:'gal',
    inline: true
});
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="inline" href="#inline_content">Inline HTML</a>
<div id="inline_content">
    <iframe></iframe> //Video here
    <p>Description here.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I use title, but I need to add a description as well and information like date, author. I would like to append a div there.

Comment: Then the easiest method would be to use the `inline: true` property. I have updated my answer.

Comment: yes, do you think I could something like this to use images (with a scale like default behaviour for images in this plugin) instead of videos there?

Comment: Absolutely, you can add what ever you want into your `#inline_content` as the Colorbox plugin with scale and fit according to the content within. You can also set a `maxWidth` and `maxHeight` for better display.